# Chrome devtools keep opening minified js file on breakpoint even if its not open

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've a really annoying problem on recent `Chrome` version `75.0.3770.90`, also on `Canary` and `Dev` versions (`Win 10 Build 18362`). I'm developing an `Angular` app and when I'm setting up a breakpoint in dev tools, it keeps opening the minified `app.js`, which causing the whole chrome to freeze. It's annoying and it seriously undermines my work productivity. Also I noticed this with tests, there it opens `karma-test-shim.js` file with the same effect. I know by reading all possible forum posts, freezes caused by opening large minified files are common, but my problem is why it even opens if I don't have breakpoint there? On the other hand, if I blackbox the minified scripts, then I can't open the `.ts` files (the dev tool doesn't find them), which is, again useless for me.

[image]

*Img: Although the breakpoint is set in .ts file, the app.js keeps opening up (it was previously closed).*

I don't know if this is issue in my set-up or if is a Chrome issue, but I'll be thankful if someone could help me with this frustrating issue.

Comment: Dumb question, but what happens if you let it open and resume to your debugging ? Does it switch to it, or does it open only the files with the breakpoints ?

Comment: It breaks on breakpoint in .ts file which is correct behaviour. It does nothing with minified file. And this is the strangest to me. Why does it open if it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Well I can't tell you, I have never faced this issue. But at least you have a workaround to it ! You could maybe [report a chrome issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) while you wait for a solution on here ?